# window.open("sms:...") works for android but not for ios

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, sms, window.open

I have this function, which pre-fills sms text message on click. This works on Android, but on any version if iOS, it just open new empty window. Any idea, why?

```
 var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var url;
        
    if (ua.indexOf("iphone") > -1 || ua.indexOf("ipad") > -1)
    {
   

    var v = (navigator.appVersion).match(/OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/);
    var ver = [parseInt(v[1], 10), parseInt(v[2], 10), parseInt(v[3] || 0, 10)];
    if (ver[0] >= 8)
    {
    url = "sms:&body=" + encodeURIComponent("Hello guys, this is an awesome app! Check it out http://www.myurl.com/webapp/index.html");
    }
    else
    {
    url = "sms:;body=" + encodeURIComponent("Hello guys, this is an awesome app! Check it out http://www.myurlcom/webapp/index.html");
    }
    
    
    }
    else
    url = "sms:?body=" + encodeURIComponent("Hello guys, this is an awesome app! Check it out http://www.muyrl.com/webapp/index.html");

    window.open (url,'_system')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with a proper HTML link, and it works well on iOS 9.

`<a href="sms:+467111111111?&body=Hello my friend">Send SMS</a>`

So I can see two potential issues :

- I might not work with `window.open();`
- It only works when a number is provided

**Edit:** I managed to make it work without a number

`<a href="sms:?&body=Hello my friend">Send SMS</a>`

So it seems to come from `window.open()`

Comment: Thank you for tests, I'll try to think of a way working around window.open and see where it leads

Answer (score 0):

The link below should help you test all the different combinations.
Just open it from your cellphone.

What has been working for me is: `href="sms://&body=TEST"`

[list of sms combination format here](https://jonathanstark.com/labs/sms-test.html)