# window.open(“sms:…”) works for android but not for ios ionic 1

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, window.open

I have this function, which pre-fills sms text message on click. This works on Android, but on iOS, it is not opening sms app. Any idea, why?
 I have seen this kind of question but that answer is not working in my case.
[window.open("sms:...") works for android but not for ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360417/window-opensms-works-for-android-but-not-for-ios)

below is my code :>

```
             if(msg=='a'){
               $scope.smsText = 'I am outside';
               window.open("sms:"+$scope.userMobileNo+"?&body="+" \n "+ localStorage.getItem('firstName') + " " + "(AppName) : "+$scope.smsText);
               $("#smsModel").hide();
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I posted my question I found a solution for it.

```
var the_link = "sms:;"+$scope.userMobile+"?&body="+encodeURIComponent(" \n "+ $scope.smsText+ localStorage.getItem('firstName') + " : " + "(Lunchbox) ");
                 location.href=the_link;
```

this code is worked for me to open SMS app with multiple receivers.

below is the link where I found the solution.

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Oct/09/Prefilling-an-SMS-on-Mobile-Devices-with-the-sms-Uri-Scheme